# The `GLIBC_2.29 not found` problem of the installation of transformers?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, glibc, huggingface-transformers

To run transformers I installed it on CentOS 8 by

```
conda install -c conda-forge transformers=4.12.2
```

following the method on [this page](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/problem-installing-using-conda/5518/2), but I still encountered the same error:

> version `GLIBC_2.29’ not found

Then I tried to install that from the huggingface channel and got stuck by lots of conflicts.

```
conda install -c huggingface transformers=4.12.2
```

At last I tried to install the `glibc231` myself, and downloaded the rpm from [this link](http://mirror.ghettoforge.org/distributions/gf/el/7/testing/x86_64/glibc231-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64.rpm), but I saw the following error, leading me to think that I would be in the wrong direction:

> Error:  Problem: conflicting requests
>
> - nothing provides glibc-common = 2.31-3.gf.el7 needed by glibc231-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64
> - nothing provides glibc-langpack = 2.31-3.gf.el7 needed by glibc231-2.31-3.gf.el7.x86_64

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issues, and I downgraded to the following version:

```
tokenizers=0.10.1 
transformers=4.6.1
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. I recommend those who encountered the same problem work around it by using [a docker image](https://hub.docker.com/u/huggingface) like me. The issues don't arise on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error. If you don't want to downgrade (which may or may not lose features), I solved it by building it from sources. You can find the instructions here:

https://huggingface.co/docs/tokenizers/python/latest/installation/main.html#installation-from-sources

Note at least two caveats in the guide above:

1. The process will ask you to install `rust`, which is a language very robust to different platforms. You might even have it on your system if you've worked with `rust` before, but in that case do remember to update your `rust` toolchain with `rustup update`.
2. If you follow the process exactly, you will install the latest commit on `master`, which might or might not be a good thing. I recommend you select your desired version and do a `git checkout ...` first before you run `python setup.py install`.